# c11: use _Generic raise SIGSEGV

Tags: c, macros, c11

here is my code, I try sample code from [here](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define type_idx(T) _Generic( (T), char: 1, int: 2, long: 3, default: 0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts(type_idx("smth"));
}
```

the output in clion is:

```
/home/roroco/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/c9a7a4c5/c9a7a4c5/Debug/ex/ex
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

and here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(c)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-4.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-4.9)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `"smth"` decays into a pointer of type `char*`, which will get translated to the default clause of _Generic. You get the value 0, so your code is equivalent to

```
puts(0);
```

Which doesn't make any sense and will cause your program to crash.

Comment: Put a `const` in there so I could upvote with a clear conscience.

Comment: @Bathsheba But the edit made the answer incorrect. `char*` (due to conversion from `char[N]`) is the correct type.

Comment: I'll put it back, with apologies.

Comment: Edited the post: to be picky, the literal itself is of type `char [5]` which then decays into a pointer to char.